# How to make this script shorter

Tags: php

```
if(!empty($act2) && empty($l2)) {
         unset($act2);
         unset($l2);         
}

if($act2 == "empty" && !empty($l2)) {
         unset($act2);
         unset($l2);         
} 

if(!empty($act3) && empty($l3)) {
         unset($act3);
         unset($l3);         
}

if($act3 == "empty" && !empty($l3)) {
         unset($act3);
         unset($l3);                 
}

if(!empty($act4) && empty($l4)) {
         unset($act4);
         unset($l4);             
}

if($act4 == "empty" && !empty($l4)) {
         unset($act4);
         unset($l4);         
}
```

//

```
if(!empty($l1) && !empty($act1) && empty($l2) && empty($act2) && empty($l3) && empty($act3) && empty($l4) && empty($act4)) { $validOrder = "true"; $l2 = ""; $act2 = ""; $l3 = ""; $act3 = ""; $l4 = ""; $act4 = ""; }
if(!empty($l1) && !empty($act1) && !empty($l2) && !empty($act2) && empty($l3) && empty($act3) && empty($l4) && empty($act4)) { $validOrder = "true"; $l3 = ""; $act3 = ""; $l4 = ""; $act4 = ""; }
if(!empty($l1) && !empty($act1) && !empty($l2) && !empty($act2) && !empty($l3) && !empty($act3) && empty($l4) && empty($act4)) { $validOrder = "true"; $l4 = ""; $act4 = "";}
if(!empty($l1) && !empty($act1) && !empty($l2) && !empty($act2) && !empty($l3) && !empty($act3) && !empty($l4) && !empty($act4)) { $validOrder = "true"; }
```

Basically, I have a form, and a php code, in the first part before the // it validates, if the link is set and the the act empty and if the act is empty and link is set, if it is so it unsets the link and the action. In the second part it checks for a valid order, so the person can't create a link only with act1 & 4 but follows an arthmetic order, and set's the variables empty. How to make it shorter, and more effecient.

Comment: I think this belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Instead of using separate variables, you could create an array with all the data and then simply create a function where you pass the array and what keys to check.

Comment: +GrumpyCrouton, you answered the old questions, what is wrong with this ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, not sure this will make the code looks shorter and kind dynamic for your multiple variable pairs.

```
$act_array = array("act2","act3","act4");
$l_array = array("l2","l3","l4");

$x = 1; 

While ($x <= 3 )
{
  if(!empty($act_array[x+1]) && empty($l_array[x+1])) 
   {
         unset($act_array[x+1]);
         unset($l_array[x+1]);             
   }

 if($act_array[x+1] == "empty" && !empty($l_array[x+1])) 
   {
         unset($act_array[x+1]);
         unset($l_array[x+1]);         
   }

  $x++;
}
```

Comment: and the second part is okay so :o ?

Comment: @JDaniels I put an extra `)` in the `unset($act_array[x+1]) );` and in the next part as well, just remove that

Comment: and for the 2nd part, I think it is good since it is a quite customized codition, no common part could be shared, so just leave as that is

Comment: @JDaniels let me check

Comment: @JDaniels, check now, modified the array declare part